# Como ler e renderizar um arquivo.txt no template do Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Como eu faço para renderizar os dados de um `arquivo.txt` num template do Django?

conteúdo do arquivo:

```
1;'one';'foo'

2;'two';'bar'
```

Eu retorno no template

> 1 - one - foo
>
> 2 - two - bar

Alguma dica de por onde eu começo?

Seguindo o site http://www.coderholic.com/parsing-csv-data-in-python/

Eu tentei o seguinte:

```
def display_text_file():
    with open('output.csv', 'rt') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        fields = r.next()
        for row in r:
            items = zip(fields, row)
            item = {}
            for (name, value) in items:
                item[name] = value.strip()
```

Agora como eu retorno isso no context da view para iterar pelos valores no template?

Eu tentei

```
{% for line in lines %}
    <p>{{ line.id  }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Na verdade é um TXT mesmo.

Comment: Você tem certeza que você quer manter o dado em CSV, ao invés de empurrar pra um SGBD?

Comment: Sim, eu preciso testar local, antes de subir pra produção.

Comment: …a implicação é que você não tem um banco de dados de teste pra desenvolvimento local?

Comment: A intenção dessa linha e das seguintes é construir um dicionário usando a primeira linha do CSV como “cabeçalho” da “planilha”.

Comment: isso mesmo.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou supor que os apóstrofos `'` não existem, então o seu arquivo .txt deve ser algo como:

```
1;one;foo
2;two;bar
3;foo;bar
```

Cada linha seria equivalente a uma linha de banco de dados, este formato é bem semelhante ao CSV, portanto acredito que você possa usar https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Deve ser algo como:

```
import csv

with open('arquivo.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader:
        print 'ID: %s Nome: %s Extra: ' %(row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

Pelo layout, me parece que o array é do tipo index (0...99 por exemplo) e não "associativa":

```
{% for line in lines %}
    <p>{{ line.id  }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Acredito que os dados teriam que ser passados desta maneira:

```
import csv

item = []

with open('arquivo.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader:
        tmp = {}
        tmp['id']    = row[0]
        tmp['name']  = row[1]
        tmp['extra'] = row[2]
        item.append(tmp)
```

Faz algum tempo que não trabalho com python, mas acredito ser isto. Me avise se houver algum exception.

Comment: Eu esqueci de falar que não está renderizando no template do Django, eu tentei jogar no context, mas não sei o que colocar la, se spamreader ou outra coisa.

Comment: Não sei como você está usando o layout, não vi código algum na sua pergunta @RegisdaSilva , por favor forneça um exemplo minimo do template e de como está tentando adicionar os dados

Comment: eu editei a pergunta.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva veja se lhe ajuda após esta edição

Comment: Thanks @Guilherme Nascimento.

Comment: Por que ao invés de "supor que os caractéres `'` não existem" e criar um `reader` com o quotechar `|` você não cria um reader com quotechar `'` e atende ao problema do usuário?

Comment: Acho que entendi o que você quiz dizer @jsbueno a questão é que quando eu falei *"`'` não existem"* ainda não tinhamos noção se a estrutura de dados (isto se referia a postagem antes da edição http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/71231/1) que o autor iria usar era realmente equivalente o CSV e estava tentando sugerir um exemplo mais simples. Contudo, ao que me parece o autor não tinha realmente um "formato" de arquivo definido, ao que me parece a resposta atendeu a duvida dele. Vou editar assim que possivel - estou no celular :). Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Não é complicado, levando em consideração que o arquivo se chama *file.txt*, está no root do projeto e está com esse conteúdo:

```
1;one;foo
2;two;bar
```

Sua app com uma estrutura parecida com esse:

```
├── admin.py
├── __init__.py
├── migrations
│   └── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── templates
│   └── csv
│       └── csv.html
├── tests.py
└── views.py
```

E seu template com um conteúdo parecido com esse:

```
{% for line in lines%}
    <p>{{ line.id }} - {{ line.nro }} - {{ line.word }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Basicamente a view precisa ter algo como isso:

```
import csv
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response


def render_csv(request):
    lines = []
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        for line in reader:
            lines.append(
                {'id': line[0], 'nro': line[1], 'word': line[2]}
            )

    return render_to_response(
        'csv/csv.html',
        {'lines': lines}
    )
```

Explicando o que está sendo feito.

1. Primeiro estamos lendo o arquivo *txt* (que na verdade é um arquivo *csv*) através do pacote **csv** (built-in do python)
2. Iteremos nesse arquivo para montar a lista de items que posteriormente será utilizada no *context* do response.
3. Por último utilizamos o shortcut **render_to_response** do django que recebe como parâmetro o caminho do template e o context.

A resposta html fica algo como:

```
<p>1 - one - foo</p>
<p>2 - two - bar</p>
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Sua resposta ajudou sim, mas eu já havia validade a resposta anterior antes, mas valeu, para futuras versões sua solução tb serve.